# Put a phone number in annotation view in mapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I want to put phone number in third line in annotation view at that press i want to call that number.

any suggestion or any tutorial....

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom annotation with some sort of custom UIButton and when that button is pressed it calls that number?